# Is there a better way of sending charts via e-mail than screenshots?

Tags: php, html, css, screenshot

My boss has tasked me with a brand new function for our statistics backend - "Share chart". We have made a standalone php file that renders the chart, and my boss wants me to write a PHP script that somehow captures the standalone php file as a PNG image and allows for sending via mail.

Researching this, it's starting to seem like creating screenshots with PHP is a difficult task, and in fact cannot be done with PHP alone.

I am currently completely clueless to whether mailing html+css would be a better solution than mailing a screenshot, and to how I would go about creating the screenshot in the first place.

I would like the experts' opinion on this, as well as perhaps some links to services that allow for simple screenshotting. I'm thinking something like:

```
http://service.com/snap.php?code=*****&url=www.google.com&size=800x600&format=png
```

Thanks for any opinions and tips

Comment: You are going to have a TOUGH time making HTML / CSS to look right in emails. I make html emails now and then and I am forced to use tables because the clients are so bad.

Comment: `tables` _are_ HTML/CSS last time I checked @danix :)

Comment: If you want to "write a PHP script that somehow captures the standalone php file as a PNG image", a relatively easy way might be to use [wkhtmltoimage](http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/).

Comment: @JMC Creative tables don't need CSS to be styled :)

Comment: @danix neither does anything else, but it sure is nice.

Comment: @JMC Creative go ahead and make a layout using divs with no css, then tell me how it went.

Comment: I get your point @danix, but still a table with no styles is not something anyone would want to look at. And putting styles within the html tags like `<table border"2">` is not a clean way to code.

Comment: @JMC Creative I didn't say it was, but email clients render it properly, unlike CSS, which was my original point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to use SVG graphics - it is vector XML graphics. So it is realtievly simple to generate, attach it and send :-)

http://w3schools.com/svg/default.asp

Comment: You could also then convert the SVG to a PNG for emailing.

Answer (score 2):

Embedding HTML in the email is not reliable, based on my experience. The problem is you cannot control what email clients your users use. Even with MS Outlook, some users may render their emails as plain text instead of HTML. In this case, all they see is bunch of ugly looking HTML tags. I don't like attaching screen-shots either simply because it takes up a lot of storage in the email accounts, and it's going to be problematic especially if your company email account has a quota.

I have tried a few solutions, for me, the best approach is to send them a link that will bring them to the web report in the browser. It doesn't take up space in the email account and I can assure the report will get rendered properly.

Comment: If you structure your email code correctly, you will send 2 versions of a mail: One for users with plain-text view, and an html version for everybody else.

Answer (score 1):

When faced with situations like this I often generate the output in HTML then use [a utility](http://www.websupergoo.com/products.htm#pd) to convert that to PDF, then attach the PDF. Email clients cannot be depended upon to deliver rich content in the body of the message.